# Unity C# , Static WaitUntil and WaitWhile, is it possible?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, caching, static, coroutine

Hello I am trying to cache WaitUntil and WaitWhile coroutine yields to use around my code, like this:

`public static WaitUntil WaitUntilPlayer0Init => () => PlayerManager.player0 != null;`

And then use in my code like this:

```
      yield return Helpers.WaitUntilPlayer0Init();
```

Throws some errors, I can't really fully understand the lambdas, and also even if this is possible, thanks!

Comment: Don't have an editor in front of me to try this but have you tried `public static WaitUntil WaitUntilPlayer0Init = new WaitUntil(()=>PlayerManager.player0!=null);`?

Comment: Questions about debugging should include verbatim errors that are encountered btw. see [ask] for more info

Comment: @Ruzihm Thanks! I will try to formulate the questions better next time! And your code does work, thanks!

Comment: You could maybe even make it `public static readonly WaitUntil = new WaitUntil (() => PlayerManager.player0!=null);` so it isn't recreated every time

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it, you just need to instantiate a `WaitUntil` with that lambda:

```
public static WaitUntil WaitUntilPlayer0Init = 
        new WaitUntil(()=>PlayerManager.player0!=null);
```